# Haskell Squeal SQL library - Type error with MonadReader

Tags: sql, haskell, servant, data-kinds

I'm building a Haskell `Servant` API using an SQL library called `Squeal`:
https://github.com/morphismtech/squeal

**I need help getting the types correct so the app compiles.**

My **Schema** is of type

```
type Schema = '["users" ::: UsersTable, ...]
type Schemas = Public Schema
```

Where `Public` is a type family for a single schema database. It's from:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/squeal-postgresql-0.5.1.0/docs/Squeal-PostgreSQL-Schema.html

I'm trying to pass the Connection Pool in a Reader like this:

```
import qualified Squeal.PostgreSQL             as S
import qualified Squeal.PostgreSQL.Pool        as SPG

newtype AppT m a
    = AppT
    { runApp :: ReaderT SquealPool (ExceptT ServerError m) a
    } deriving
    ( Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader SquealPool, MonadError ServerError
    , MonadIO
    )

type App = AppT IO

type SquealPool = SPG.Pool (SQ.K S.Connection Schema)
```

My SQL query & session are something like this:

```
emailQuery :: Query_ Schemas (Only Text) UserEmail
emailQuery = select (#email `as` #email)
                    (from (table #users) & where_ (#email .== param @1))

emailTakenSession
    :: (MonadReader SquealPool m, MonadPQ Schemas m, MonadIO m)
    => Text
    -> m UserEmail
emailTakenSession email = do
    result <- runQueryParams emailQuery (Only email)
    email  <- getRow 1 result
    return email
```

Finally, I'm using them in the `Servant` handlers like this:

```
emailTaken :: MonadIO m => Text -> AppT m APIEmail
emailTaken emailStr = do
    pool   <- ask -- this produces error
    result <- liftIO $ runPoolPQ (Q.emailTakenSession emailStr) pool
    return $ APIEmail result True
```

### Problem

The compiler reports an error in `ask` in `emailTaken`:

```
 * Couldn't match kind `[(ghc-prim-0.5.3:GHC.Types.Symbol,
                         Squeal.PostgreSQL.Schema.SchemumType)]'
                 with `Squeal.PostgreSQL.Schema.SchemumType'
```

From what I understand, it's trying to match type family `Schemas` with type `Schema`.

### Question

**How do I need to edit the type signatures to get this to compile and work?**
Particularly `emailTakenSession` is probably off at least.

---

### Solution

In the interest of completeness for other readers, I needed to change

```
type SquealPool = SPG.Pool (SQ.K S.Connection Schema)
```

into

```
type SquealPool = SPG.Pool (S.K S.Connection '["public" ::: Schema])
```

The type family would resolve to this anyway, and this way I'm not providing an  illegal construct (a type family) to MonadReader derivation in `AppT`.

Comment: I couldn't find a question. Could you point out what it is?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added a question at the end. The problem is types/kinds, mainly with Schema vs Schemas and how to write the type signatures of functions accordingly.

Comment: Please include your question into the section above. It makes it easier for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a skeleton of how I combine Squeal & Servant.

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    DataKinds
  , OverloadedLabels
  , OverloadedStrings
  , PolyKinds
#-}

module SquealServant where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.String
import Servant
import Squeal.PostgreSQL
import Data.Pool

type DB = Public Schema

type Schema = '[] -- your schema here

type API = Get '[JSON] String -- your api here

type PoolDB = Pool (K Connection DB)

application :: PoolDB -> Application
application pool = serve api (server pool)

server :: PoolDB -> Server API
server pool = hoistServer api (handler pool) serverT

handler :: PoolDB -> PQ DB DB IO x -> Handler x
handler pool session = do
  errOrResult <- liftIO . usingConnectionPool pool $
    trySqueal (transactionally_ session)
  case errOrResult of
    Left err -> throwError (sqlErr err)
    Right result -> return result

sqlErr :: SquealException -> ServerError
sqlErr err = err500 { errBody = fromString (show err) }

api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy

serverT :: ServerT API (PQ DB DB IO)
serverT = hello

hello :: PQ DB DB IO String
hello = do
  Only greeting <- getRow 0 =<< runQuery helloQ
  return greeting

helloQ :: Query_ DB () (Only String)
helloQ = values_ ("hello world" `as` #fromOnly)

usingConnectionPool :: PoolDB -> PQ DB DB IO x -> IO x
usingConnectionPool pool (PQ session) = unK <$> withResource pool session
```

Comment: Thanks! My problem is more accurately that I can't derive a `MonadReader` instance from my `AppT` if I use `Schemas` instead of `Schema` in `type SquealPool` (`type PoolDB` in yours). Since `Schemas` is a type family

Comment: You can probably evaluate the type family to `'["public" ::: Schema]`